# cannot set background color on dropdown from React native paper dropdown

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-paper

I used a react-native-paper-dropdown and the styles I am applying wont get set for example the background color wont change;

```
<DropDown
      // label={''}
      mode="flat"
      visible={showDropDown}
      showDropDown={() => setShowDropDown(true)}
      onDismiss={() => setShowDropDown(false)}
      value={country}
      setValue={setCountry}
      list={countriesList}        
      dropDownStyle={{
        width: 100,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        borderColor: 'white',
        shadowColor: 'white',
    }}
  />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this code worked for me to change background color of the dropdown.
```

```
    <DropDown
      // label={'P'}
      mode={'outlined'}
      visible={showMobileDropDOwn}
      showDropDown={() => setShowMobileDropDOwn(true)}
      onDismiss={() => setShowMobileDropDOwn(false)}
      setValue={setPhoneCountry}
      value={phoneCountry}
      list={codes}
      inputProps={{
        style:{
          width:90,
          backgroundColor: 'rgb(252,243,207)',
          height:20
        }
      }}
    />
```

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend you to use the below library for implementing dropdown

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dropdown-picker

Much easier to use and it is popular library